# Does “Optimized Battery Charging” require “Location Services” to be enabled?

Tags: mac, battery, charging, apple-silicon

My Mac is almost always connected to a powered Thunderbolt 3 dock and noticed battery cycle count is 48 and maximum capacity is 89% (lower than I expected after less than 2 years of use).

Does “Optimized Battery Charging” require “Location Services” to be enabled?

For privacy reasons, I typically disable “Location Services”.

Comment: You accepted [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455090/149366). Does that mean that you enabled "Location Services" on your ***Mac***, and Optimized Battery Charging started working?

Comment: @Seamus I did enable “Location Services” and now, “Optimized Battery Charging” sometimes work… what appears to trigger things working is using Mac on battery more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes, Location Services must be enabled.

According to the Apple Support document, [About Optimized Battery Charging on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210512), it specifically states that Location Services must be enabled

> #### Make sure that these settings are enabled:
>
> - Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services > Location Services.
> - Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services > System Services > System Customization.
> - Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services > System Services > Significant Locations > Significant Locations.

[Optimized battery charging](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212049) “learns” your charging habits, for instance, you plug it in at overnight when at home.

Comment: Would you happen to have recommendations when computer is almost always connected to powered Thunderbolt 3 dock (not sure “Optimized Battery Charging” would apply)? Should I ask a separate question?

Comment: Also, does anyone happen to have link to Mac docs (vs iPhone) that mention “Location Services” requirement?

Comment: That’s been asked several times and there are so many opinions on the matter.  Your device has already been engineered to not over/under charge the battery.  Just leave it plugged in.  It will automatically stop charging when “full.”  Just use it as you intended.  You won’t prolong the life in any statistically significant way.

Comment: But how can battery be at 89% after just 1 year and 4 months? Isn’t that excessive aging for only 48 cycle counts? Btw, read all I could find before asking here.

Comment: It’s a contained chemical reaction that produces the electrons to power your Mac.  In other words, it’s not perfect. See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259621/119271) for more info.

Comment: The [referenced article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210512) in this answer is for ***iOS***  - not macOS.  What gives?