# MacBook battery versus Tesla or Chevy Battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I am curious to know from other users who are knowledgable with LiION batteries.  I work on a MacBook and just recently got a new machine.  From all my research of LiIon batteries, the optimal life to maintain the charge from studying EV-Car technology is to maintain charge from 20%-80%.

Is the same true on the MacBook?

Since both use LiIon i figure there should be parallels, but I figure there are differences with power management which may be chip-based.

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Tri

Comment: Also:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212504/whats-the-best-way-to-prolong-the-lifespan-of-a-macbook-pro-battery/230227#230227

Comment: See also this:https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries